# How to pick records that have lower rank than a specific record in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Suppose there's a ranked comment list, and I want to implement relay-style pagination on it.

For example I have this query:

```sql
SELECT 
  comment.id,
  (comment.like_count * 0.5 + comment.reply_count * 3) AS score
FROM 
  comment
WHERE
  comment.is_deleted = false
ORDER BY score desc
LIMIT 10;
```

And the ranked comment IDs are in this order: `[20, 1, 4, 12, 9, 5]`

Now a user passes a cursor `12`, and wants to query ranked comments after ID 12, in this case `[9, 5]`

How can I implement this in PostgreSQL?

---

Edit: I figured out another way to achieve this by adding a cache layer. So the implementation becomes:

- Get the IDs from cache (for example Redis)
- find the index of `cursor` in the array
- If the index > -1, then slice the array
- Query the database using `WHERE IN`

That solves my problem, but if anyone could help with the original quesion, I'd appreciate.

Comment: Just don't use the *id* `12` as the cursor. Use the *score* value for the cursor!